# ldap_search function succeed.But ldap_count_entries gives Zero(0)?

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory, ldap

i am using c++(not Vc++) for my project.

i want to access a AD using ldap functions.

it will succeed till ldap_search functions.but after that ldap_count_entries gives NULL(0).

what is the problem?

Comment: Because the search is valid, but there simply isn't anything matching what you search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search parameters:

- base object
- search scope
- filter

returned no entries, or the access controls associated with the authorization state prevented any entries from being returned to the LDAP client.